# Get system's date delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, office365

I need to import various Excel files into an Access database. There are two date columns that use all possible formattings like `01.05.2020` or `01,05,2020` or `01/05/2020` depending on how they were created. Sometimes it's valid date and another time it's just a string.

The Access application will be running on different systems too, so they might be using different delimiters. This means I cannot just replace all `.` or `,` with `/`. I am going to create a replace function that would normalize the string for whatever system it is running on but I cannot figure out how to get the **current system's date delimiter**.

Is VBA able to give me that information?

Comment: Oh, I've just came up with a dirty workaround. I use the `Date` function, assign it to a string and check which character is the delimiter.

Comment: You could make a Windows API call to retrieve this information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [XlApplicationInternational](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlapplicationinternational) enum with the `Application.International` property to retrieve this configuration.

This returns `/` on my system:

> ```
> Excel.Application.International(xlApplicationInternational.xlDateSeparator)
> ```

If you're in an Access host, you'll want to avoid using the global `Excel.Application` object, and use an instance that you own and that you can `Quit` once you're done:

```
Dim app As Excel.Application
Set app = New Excel.Application
Debug.Print app.International(xlApplicationInternational.xlDateSeparator)
'...
app.Quit
```

Comment: It's nice Excel provides this info.  Is it just a wrapper around the WinAPI?

Comment: Cool, and when prefixed with `Excel.` then it also works with [tag:ms-access] :-]

Comment: @BrianMStafford it looks like it is - basically there's an enum constant for every configurable character in Windows' *Regional Settings* dialog.

Comment: Note that this returns the `sDate` registry key, which does not necessarily equal to what is used in the _Short Date_ date format VBA uses (which is in `sShortDate`). It should work for most cases, though.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Not really, there are many missing enums, for example the _Short Date_ and _Long Date_ formats are not available as far as I can see. Also note: creating a new excel application object just to read a registry key has a lot of overhead.

Comment: @ErikA OP very likely *already* has an `Excel.Application` instance handy though, given the nature of the code. Also it's not so much about the date format strings, the enum also encodes what characters are used in date format strings..

Comment: @t3chb0t make sure you don't refer to some global-scope implicit `Excel.Application` instance, see edit (if your Access app closes and there are "ghost" EXCEL.EXE processes in Task Manager, that would be why)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Regarding the Excel application: no code has been shared and the question is tagged ms-access too, so I wouldn't be so sure. Regarding the formats, you have no way to reconstruct the _Long Date_ format from the `xlApplicationInternational` enum, and can only make an educated guess. Take for example the Japanese date format `yyyy年M月d日`. You can't reconstruct that from what you currently gave, you need `sShortDate`

Comment: @ErikA fair enough, that is correct. I was just answering the question asked in the title, which was about the delimiter/separator character (which *does* exist as such in the Excel OM), not the format string.

Comment: You were right with the Excel process. I have 78 ghost instances of it LOL

Comment: @t3chb0t ouch! make sure all `Application` member calls are explicitly qualified with the `Excel.Application` instance you own, e.g. use `app.Worksheets` instead of `Excel.Worksheets` or just `Worksheets` (literally every other VBA example out there is doing it wrong); the implicitly-qualified calls will spawn an implicit `Application` that you don't want around :)

Answer (score 7):

The truly simple and fastest method is to let VBA do the job as the character "**/**" to *Format* designates the date separator:

```
' Get localised date separator.
DateSeparator = Format(Date, "/")

' Denmark -> "-"
' Germany -> "."
' US      -> "/"
```

Why this works:

> **(/)** - Date separator. In some locales, other characters may be used to represent the date separator. The date separator separates the day, month, and year when date values are formatted. The actual character used as the date separator in formatted output is determined by your system settings.

from [User-defined date/time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#user-defined-datetime-formats)

Comment: @BigBen maybe. Feels a bit hackish though; I'd want there to be a comment if that were to be used in production code, whereas `Excel.Application.International` says what it does, and does what it says. OTOH this will work directly off the standard library, since that is `VBA.Strings.Format`: upvoted!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: In-line comment added.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon indeed, it's a nice trick but doesn't seem to be that hackish. I quoted the part from the documentation that confirms the mechanics of it (I was curious why it work so I checked it). I think this solution is also ok. I virtually accept it too ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t nice edit, I guess that otherwise useless "thank you" button can mean "here's a virtual other upvote" =) with a comment that prevents a maintainer from having to lookup the docs, it's a great solution BTW

Comment: I believe this is the best solution, because it doesn't depend on Excel and can be used with any VBA host app.